# Cocoon gem: protect nested associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

I have 3 models in my Rails 4.2 app:

```
class Vintage < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :grapers, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :grapes, through: :grapers  

  attr_accessible :grapers_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :grapers, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :grapes 

end


class Grape < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :grapers
  has_many :vintages, through: :grapers 

end


class Graper < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :vintage
  belongs_to :grape

  attr_accessible :grape_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :grape, reject_if: :all_blank
  attr_accessor :name

end
```

My cocoon form with nested attributes is working well.
My uniq problem is I don't want to allow to create/update grapes through the nested form.

My *vintage* owns many *grapers* associated to *grapes*. I don't want the app can create/update grapes through this form. I have another form to add grapes.
I just want to use the nested form to attach grapes to vintage through grapers.

What did I miss ? How to forbid the app to edit grapes through the nested form ?

Actually, for example, if I enter "Merlo" and don't click on "Merlot" row, the app will change "Merlot" to "Merlo" in my database !

EDIT: Code in my view:

```
<%= link_to_add_association 'Add grape', f, :grapers, 'data-association-insertion-node' => "#vintage-grapes ol", 'data-association-insertion-method' => "append", :wrap_object => Proc.new {|graper| graper.build_grape; graper }, :partial => '/admin/vintages/graper_field' %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want `grapes` to be created then you should remove.

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :grapes
```

You cocoon form should generate `graper` forms from which you can choose but not edit `grapes`.

Also in your sanitizer do not permit `grapes_parameters`.

Comment: In fact, I have already removed "accepts_nested_attributes_for :grapes " in the vintage model. But I can yet change a grape name for example. What do you mean by grape_parameters in my sanitizer ? I added my link_to_add_association in the main message.

Comment: OK, I commented "attr_accessible :grape_attributes" in the graper model. Seems to work: I can't change a graper grape already saved. I need to remove the graper (grape) and add a new one if I want to change.

Comment: The default rails `sanitizer` is `strong_parameters` and you do not have to comment `attr_accessible`.